# PostgreSQL recursive query performance improvement

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, recursive, explain

I'm building a database which is used to derive hierarchical relations for which I chose a PostgreSQL recursive CTE .

my table structure is

```
table_name             |column_name           |data_type               |
-----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
source_relationship_dev|relationship_id       |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject               |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|predicate             |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|object                |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_date              |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|provided_by           |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|harvested_date        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject_status        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|object_status         |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|source_relationship_id|integer                 |
source_relationship_dev|correction_id         |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|harvested_date        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|obj_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|obj                   |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|predicate             |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|provided_by           |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|start_date            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|sub_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject               |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|audit_created_date    |timestamp with time zone|
source_relationship_dev|audit_created_by      |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|audit_modified_date   |timestamp with time zone|
source_relationship_dev|audit_modified_by     |character varying       |
```

Index:

```
table_name             |column_name           |data_type               |
-----------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
source_relationship_dev|relationship_id       |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject               |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|predicate             |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|object                |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_date              |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|provided_by           |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|harvested_date        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject_status        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|object_status         |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|source_relationship_id|integer                 |
source_relationship_dev|correction_id         |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|harvested_date        |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|obj_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|obj                   |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|predicate             |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|provided_by           |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|rel_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|start_date            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|sub_status            |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|subject               |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|audit_created_date    |timestamp with time zone|
source_relationship_dev|audit_created_by      |character varying       |
source_relationship_dev|audit_modified_date   |timestamp with time zone|
source_relationship_dev|audit_modified_by     |character varying       |
```

My query:

```
select 
    correction_id as id,
    subject,
    obj,
    predicate,
    start_date
    from
(
with recursive cte as (
        select
            correction_id,
            subject ,
            predicate ,
            obj ,
            start_date,
            provided_by,
            harvested_date
        from
            source_relationship_dev
        where
            obj_status != 'DELETE'
            and rel_status != 'DELETE'
            and sub_status != 'DELETE'
    union all
        select
            c.correction_id,
            c.subject ,
            c.predicate ,
            c.obj ,
            c.start_date,
            c.provided_by,
            c.harvested_date
        from
            source_relationship_dev c
        join cte e on
            c.subject = e.predicate
        where
            c.obj_status != 'DELETE'
            and c.rel_status != 'DELETE'
            and c.sub_status != 'DELETE'
 )
        select 
            correction_id,
            subject,
            predicate,
            obj,
            harvested_date,
            provided_by,
            start_date,
            subject || '-' || predicate || '-' || obj as stored_relationship
        from
            cte
        join relation_inferences on
            relationship = predicate
    union all
        select
            correction_id,
            obj,
            relationship,
            subject,
            harvested_date,
            provided_by,
            start_date,
            subject || '-' || predicate || '-' || obj as stored_relationship
        from
            cte
        join relation_inferences on
            inverse_relationship = predicate
    union all
        select
            correction_id||'_inverse' as relationship_id,
            obj,
            inverse_relationship,
            subject,
            harvested_date,
            provided_by,
            start_date,
            subject || '-' || predicate || '-' || obj as stored_relationship
        from
            cte
        join relation_inferences on
            relationship = predicate
    union all
        select
            correction_id||'_inverse' as relationship_id,
            subject,
            inverse_relationship,
            obj,
            harvested_date,
            provided_by,
            start_date,
            subject || '-' || predicate || '-' || obj as stored_relationship
        from
            cte
        join relation_inferences on
            inverse_relationship = predicate) as chk
            where  provided_by = (select provided_by from source_relationship_dev 
                                where subject=chk.subject
                                or obj=chk.subject
                                order by harvested_Date desc fetch first row only);
```

My Explain plan is

```
Subquery Scan on chk  (cost=313222.30..107250816.83 rows=866 width=1154) (actual time=0.043..52208.024 rows=28960 loops=1)
  Filter: ((chk.provided_by)::text = ((SubPlan 1))::text)
  ->  Append  (cost=313222.30..483994.99 rows=173152 width=1522) (actual time=0.030..103.675 rows=28960 loops=1)
        CTE cte
          ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..313221.19 rows=1731501 width=284) (actual time=0.009..28.418 rows=14481 loops=1)
                ->  Seq Scan on source_relationship_dev source_relationship_dev_1  (cost=0.00..833.42 rows=14481 width=284) (actual time=0.007..7.088 rows=14481 loops=1)
                      Filter: (((obj_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text) AND ((rel_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text) AND ((sub_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text))
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=1566.43..27775.77 rows=171702 width=284) (actual time=16.391..16.393 rows=0 loops=1)
                      Hash Cond: ((e.predicate)::text = (c.subject)::text)
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on cte e  (cost=0.00..2896.20 rows=144810 width=516) (actual time=0.005..1.590 rows=14481 loops=1)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=833.42..833.42 rows=14481 width=284) (actual time=10.504..10.505 rows=14481 loops=1)
                            Buckets: 16384  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 1973kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on source_relationship_dev c  (cost=0.00..833.42 rows=14481 width=284) (actual time=0.008..4.008 rows=14481 loops=1)
                                  Filter: (((obj_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text) AND ((rel_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text) AND ((sub_status)::text <> 'DELETE'::text))
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..41990.02 rows=43288 width=2490) (actual time=0.029..49.124 rows=7239 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((cte.predicate)::text = (relation_inferences.relationship)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on cte  (cost=0.00..34630.02 rows=1731501 width=2458) (actual time=0.010..38.674 rows=14481 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=218) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on relation_inferences  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=218) (actual time=0.002..0.004 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..41990.02 rows=43288 width=2192) (actual time=0.033..15.323 rows=7241 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((cte_1.predicate)::text = (relation_inferences_1.inverse_relationship)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on cte cte_1  (cost=0.00..34630.02 rows=1731501 width=2458) (actual time=0.001..4.770 rows=14481 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=436) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on relation_inferences relation_inferences_1  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=436) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 3"  (cost=1.11..42531.12 rows=43288 width=1708) (actual time=0.038..17.136 rows=7239 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..42098.24 rows=43288 width=1708) (actual time=0.037..15.375 rows=7239 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((cte_2.predicate)::text = (relation_inferences_2.relationship)::text)
                    ->  CTE Scan on cte cte_2  (cost=0.00..34630.02 rows=1731501 width=2458) (actual time=0.001..4.601 rows=14481 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=436) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=5 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on relation_inferences relation_inferences_2  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=436) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 4"  (cost=1.11..42531.12 rows=43288 width=1708) (actual time=0.042..16.969 rows=7241 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.11..42098.24 rows=43288 width=1708) (actual time=0.041..15.283 rows=7241 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((cte_3.predicate)::text = (relation_inferences_3.inverse_relationship)::text)
                    ->  CTE Scan on cte cte_3  (cost=0.00..34630.02 rows=1731501 width=2458) (actual time=0.001..4.816 rows=14481 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.05..1.05 rows=5 width=218) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=5 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on relation_inferences relation_inferences_3  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=218) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=5 loops=1)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..616.59 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=1.798..1.798 rows=1 loops=28960)
          ->  Index Scan using source_hrvst_idx on source_relationship_dev  (cost=0.29..1232.90 rows=2 width=33) (actual time=1.797..1.797 rows=1 loops=28960)
                Filter: (((subject)::text = (chk.subject)::text) OR ((obj)::text = (chk.subject)::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 6783
Planning Time: 0.765 ms
Execution Time: 52211.281 ms
```

This 52211.281 ms is for 14441 records.

Can I improve the performance of the query as it is rather than touching my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the recursive query, but this condition:

```
where provided_by = (select provided_by from source_relationship_dev 
                     where subject=chk.subject
                        or obj=chk.subject
                     order by harvested_Date desc fetch first row only)
```

The `OR` makes this particularly nasty, as often.

I suggest two indexes to speed up the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON source_relationship_dev (subject);
CREATE INDEX ON source_relationship_dev (obj);
```

That should lead to two index scans with a "bitmap or".